# Are .NET resource files only for localization?

Tags: .net, resx

I've used .resx files in the past to store text files and other things - queries for example. It works great because I can say Resources.Queries.BlahQuery. (Yes, I know we should probably used stored procedures, but that's another story...)

I'll never be doing any localization on these resources.

Is this a bad idea? **Am I misusing .NET resource files?**

Comment: Your queries are resources so no, you aren't misusing them. Even if your application was english only then storing all the messages in the resources still makes sense as you may need to translate it later and the overhead is minimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't say that you misuse them. Perhaps you don't use their full potential, but that is not the same as misusing them. Their name indicate what they are for; storing resources that the code uses. It *may* be that you want to localize these resources, so there are convenient mechanisms for doing so. But *not* doing so is not to be considered a misuse. Not by me anyway.